# Error: EACCES, open '/components/scholarshipr-card.html''

Tags: angular, npm, webpack

No se puede ejecutar el webpack en mi proyecto, debido a que modifique un modulo y ya no me muestra más que este error.
Este es el error que estoy recibiendo:

### Module build failed: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open

Este es el archivo de configuración del webpack

```js
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        test: path.join(__dirname, "src/entry.js")
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        publicPath: "/",
        filename: "[name].js",
        sourceMapFilename: "[file].map"
    }
};
```

Comment: Estas utilizando linux? SI es así con que usuario estas intentando leer el archivo?

Comment: así es estoy usando el WSL de linux en Windows 10 y estaba con el usuario que cree, y me di cuenta que no corría porque no tenía los permisos necesarios

Comment: Me alegro que te haya funcionado.